# Does everyone who is doing a PhD has to dabble in philosophy to a certain extent?

Tags: phd, philosophy

Does everyone who is doing a PhD has to dabble in philosophy to a certain extent?

The question is irrespective of the field of research.

Comment: _Does everyone who is doing a PhD has to dabble in philosophy to a certain extent?_ -- Not that I'm familiar with, but the world we live in is large and diverse; can you clarify where in the world you are?

Comment: I can say no, but doing that would help you in building your logical thinking.

Comment: @Mahran - Do you mean *would not help you*?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "dabble in philosophy to a certain extent". *All* educated human beings "dabble in philosophy" to at least some extent, whether they realize it or not.

Comment: _Philosophy_ comes from the greek for _love of wisdom_. In that sense, yes; doing a PhD should require a love of wisdom. In the modern sense of _what the department of philosophy does_, no; doing a PhD in computer science will not require you to have anything to do with the philosophy department.

Comment: @Thomas I agree except of what the department of philosophy does... that is quite misleading and depends of your country, in the USA and Western Europe maybe half of the world, there is the only analytical approach of research at philosophy departments. Continental Europe have also their own method.

Comment: @SSimon I have absolutely no idea what the philosophy department does and I have a PhD in Computer Science. That is the point of second half of my earlier comment.

Comment: The meaning of "philosophy" has changed since Newton kicked of what is now called "Newtonian physics" by publishing "Philosophiæ Naturalis Principia Mathematica", "The Mathematical Principles of Natural Philosophy".

Answer (score 34):

No. This is a misinterpretation of what “Ph.D.” means. The full title of the degree is *Philosophiae doctor*, technically a doctor “of philosophy.” However, this does not mean "philosophy" in the modern sense, but rather someone who pursues knowledge (“lover of wisdom”—the source of "philosophy"), not necessarily someone who studies philosophy.

Comment: +1. You could add that the more modern meaning use of the word "philosophy" to mean "what the philosophy department at your university does" is quite new, 100 years or so. Just about everything that isn't medicine, theology, or law would have been considered philosophy, hence the separate academic degree titles for those fields (not that there couldn't be some overlap, of course).

Comment: For a long time, what we now call natural science was called natural philosophy.  For example, Newton's great book on physics was titled "Philosophiae Naturalis Principia Mathematica".

Comment: I find it difficult to see how you could do a Ph.D and *avoid* philosophy altogether. You're a scientist? Cool, you need to study scientific ethics and the philosophy of science. A mathematician? Mathematics and philosophy are conjoined at the hip. Law or political science? Again, ethics, but also political philosophy. Theology? Philosophy of religion. And so on.

Comment: @ubadub “You're a scientist? Cool, you need to study scientific ethics and the philosophy of science.” -- No, I didn't. Neither did any of my colleagues, as far as I know.

Comment: @Pont OMG, really? what is the name of your institution? It is strange if they didnt teach you about plagiarism, ethics, research methodology, logic, history, social implications, etc

Comment: @SSimon: I went to and worked at multiple schools, none of which offered such training.

Comment: @SSimon The University of Otago, since you ask. There was no required taught component whatsoever to my PhD, which I believe is a fairly common state of affairs at non-American universities.

Comment: @aeismail math?

Comment: @Pont curriculum available on their website defer with your statement

Comment: @SSimon I'm unsure why you seem to think I'm lying about my own PhD, but feel free to consult the [university's PhD handbook](http://www.otago.ac.nz/graduate-research/study/phddoctoral//otago604830.pdf), which states: ‘There is no course work… Candidates are not permitted to take additional courses… The degree of Doctor of Philosophy at the University of Otago is acquired solely by the submission of a thesis…’. In other words: not only did I not study philosophy during my PhD -- I was in fact **forbidden** from enrolling in philosophy (or any other) courses during my doctoral studies.

Comment: @Pont so why they put explanation that thesis suppose to be original, novel, and logical?

Comment: question was if dabble, the link you provide is full with rules that confirm OP questions

Comment: @SSimon I think you've forgotten what we're discussing: ubadub and you claim that "you need to study scientific ethics and the philosophy of science" to do a science PhD. I've disproved this claim.

Comment: @Pont actually, you proved it. I am shocked you think we need a special course for it to be counted as learning.

Comment: @SSimon I've offered personal attestation and documentary evidence. If at this point if you'd like to go on imagining that I sneakily self-studied philosophy (or for that matter eschatology, campanology, or hierographology) during my science PhD, and that I'm trying for some reason to conceal this fact, then I can't really add much except to wish you much joy in your imaginings and a happy New Year :).

Comment: @SSimon: Understanding what’s ethical behavior is not the same as “dabbling” in philosophy. You don’t need to read Kant or Aristotle or Hobbes to get the basics of what you need as a researcher, when by and large the Golden Rule tends to be enough to steer you in the right direction.

Comment: @aeismail understanding or knowing? we are required to know all processes and points of it, plus methodology, plus there is not only science PhD.

Comment: @SSimon “We are required to know all processes and points of it.” Say what now? This is a joke, right? We’re not expected, let alone required, to know everything. That’s kind of the whole point of research. Now we are expected to act ethically, but as I mentioned, most of the time in academia, it doesn’t require specific learning to figure out what that is. As for the issue of different disciplines, somehow I suspect a French lit PhD candidate is much less likely to study ethics than a bioengineering PhD.

Comment: @aeismail but how you can act ethically if you don't know etic? but French lit going to study more philosophy than any other student, I mean OP question is not clear

Answer (score 16):

**No**.  In fact, the vast majority of PhDs do not study philosophy in any reasonable sense.

Comment: Hmm, I never met PhD student that never study ethics or any sort of ethics, it is strong emphasis now on following ethical concerns. I am surprised by your answer bcs it is rather an exception.

Comment: Well now you know me. I am a PhD student in pure mathematics, I read the Wikipedia article on the Trolley Problem once, and that's about the extent of my studies on ethics. I think this is typical of a PhD student in an unrelated area.

Comment: @SSimon: I also did not study ethics as a PhD student, and there is no ethical requirement in the PhD program in my department (of which I am the graduate coordinator).  But while students in certain fields do get instruction on "following ethical concerns," this need not be studying philosophy in any reasonable sense.  To me, this sounds a little bit like saying that someone who learns how to use a spreadsheet is studying computer science.

Comment: @SolveIt That seems spurious; the field of mathematics (both pure and applied) is heavily informed by philosophy. Some of the greatest mathematicians of the last 400 years, such as Gödel, Frege, Pascal, Descartes, Bertrand Russell (just off the top of my head) are as well known for their mathematical contributions as their philosophical contributions. Most of set theory and a good deal of number theory originates in philosophy, ultimately.

Comment: @ubadub Be that as it may, the fact remains that philosophy is not a serious academic interest of most people pursuing a graduate degree in mathematics. A great number of fields have their origins in philosophy. But mathematicians using Cartesian coordinates aren't doing philosophy any more than a software engineer using Lisp (they exist!) is doing philosophy, the influence of Alonzo Church notwithstanding.

Comment: @SolveIt we should distinguish between "doing" philosophy as philosophy Ph.Ds do (i.e. producing new research) vs. studying existing philosophy. A software engineer isn't a Ph.D student in mathematics; while a software engineer is just applying programming rules, presumably the math Ph.D is furthering the field of mathematics in a way that generally requires understanding of some of the philosophical background of his chosen field. Similarly, a computer science Ph.D working on Lisp would require a fairly deep understanding of λ-calculus, which is of course a philosophical matter

Comment: @ubadub Both perspectives make sense: Philosophy was involved in shaping the framework of modern Mathematics. But nowadays, to do research in Math, you simply apply this readily-available framework. There is no necessity to understand its philosophical influences.

Comment: @ubadub My point is that there seems to be little need to understand the philosophical background of a subject to be able to contribute to its modern form.

Comment: It depends on exactly what your contribution is; for certain areas, that's valid, but a basic understanding of the philosophy of science and of statistics would probably improve the work done by *any* scientist. To cite a contemporary example, [abuse of p-values](https://www.nature.com/news/statisticians-issue-warning-over-misuse-of-p-values-1.19503) is fundamentally rooted in  [*philosophical* misunderstandings and disagreements](http://fivethirtyeight.com/features/statisticians-found-one-thing-they-can-agree-on-its-time-to-stop-misusing-p-values/) of what p-values entail.

Comment: @ubadub I find this statement more agreeable when the focus is on empirical sciences, in which methodological questions are tied to philosophical discussions, such as the relationship between theory and reality. Math has been the subject of such discussions as well, but the actual methodology is decoupled from them.

Comment: @SolveIt field of mathematics is not science, it is much closer to philosophy or it is philosophy entirely (imaginary numbers, quantum mathematics, etc )

Comment: @PeteL.Clark you are mathematics? well, you have two, applied and pure. I think your field don't need ethics bcs it is the philosophy for itself. I mean actually, my department have Logic as subject and professors in that field, why your department doesn't have is strange to me.

Comment: also, I wonder why in the etical board of university are people from the mathematic field also @ubadub ?

Answer (score 1):

From the Greek, "philosophy" literally means the "love of wisdom".  If we define philosophy as a study that encompasses knowledge, language, and reason, then everything we study touches upon philosophy.  So in this particular sense, the answer to your question is "yes".

However, for the vast majority of PhDs (other than in philosophy, theology, and other related fields) there is no requirement to take any philosophy courses or even to know how to spell Plato.  So, in this particular sense, the answer to your question is "no".

Answer (score -6):

It depends on what is your definition of philosophy.
In my view philosophy is a discussion of 5 elements 1) Yourself 2) The nature 3) God 4) Life 5) Death
If we go by above definition P.hd is studying on at least one aspect. If one can study and understand all above aspects then he is a philosopher.
To answer your question. No most of the phd students don’t study philosophy.